# How to create dynamic IIS Web Playlists using C# and ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, smooth-streaming

I am trying to create a web playlist that can be played from remotely with clients like VLC or Windows Media Player. I've seen the resources at http://www.iis.net/learn/media/web-playlists It talks about managing playlists via the IIS interface.
Is there any way to create dynamic playlists using data from the database?
Thanks in advance.